# My website seems to not recognize some CSS values ( all "-ms" values)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I am working on a MVC website that uses Bootstrap. Since Yesterday, my page aspect has changed. It seems like the page doesn't recognize -ms values anymore (that are all over bootstrap.css)

[CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TV3Mu.jpg)

If I put my cursor on the /!\ I get "Invalid property values"

Here's the header of the layout in my MVC

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("Header", required: false)
</head>
```

And here's the content of the bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));
```

Comment: Just a quick question: Did you test this in IE? then the -ms will probably work  (and those not on the other browsers,, )

Comment: I did not test in IE, but it was working fine on my firefox until a few days ago. I'm checking right now if it works, I'll let you know.

Comment: I confirm it doesn't work on IE either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exclamations are expected. Looking for example at the 'display' tag that you show in your screenshot: it is just saying that it is ignoring the `-ms-flexbox` property and instead using `flexbox`. `-ms-flexbox` is a vendor-specific tag for Microsoft. That browser wants to use `flexbox`

Comment: Thanks. I finally found the problem. For some reason, it seems I was using the worng version of bootstrap. Reading a tutorial for older bootstraps.